# couldn't authenticate user to post in twitter by .net core from my application using twitter api.

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth, .net-core, signature

I would like to post a tweet on Twitter from my app(.net core framework) for other users. After getting access_key, I still  couldn't authenticate users. I've done this:

```
  public async Task TestTweet()
    {
        // oauth application keys
        var oauth_token = "user's access_token here";
        var oauth_token_secret = "user's access_token_secret here";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "my client_key";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "client_secret";

        // oauth implementation details
        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details

        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
        var status = "this is my tweet";
        status = Uri.EscapeDataString(status);
        var include_entities = "true";
        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "include_entities={0}&oauth_consumer_key={1}&oauth_nonce={2}&oauth_signature_method={3}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={4}&oauth_token={5}&oauth_version={6}&status={7}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    include_entities,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                    status
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(status), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(resource_url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            var data = await client.PostAsync("?status=", content);
            var response = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var abc = response.ToString();

        }

    }
```

The response is "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":32,\"message\":\"Could not authenticate you.\"}]}"